# How to translate the month name in a date select list field?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I have created a date field in user account fields. In manage form display, I have selected `Select list` as widget.

I want to translate the month names which is displaying a select list.

I checked it here `admin/config/regional/translate` and in config translation `admin/config/regional/config-translation` but I don't see any option to translate it.

Is there anything I am missing. Is it possible to translate the month names in the date select list?

Comment: `but I don't see any option to translate it` have you attempted to see that page in the other language? New strings for translations won't get picked up unless you load the page in a diff language first.

Comment: Yes, I am on the registration page, where that field appears. I reloaded the page several time. But in the interface translation when I search for a month, I can only see this `March
In Context: Long month name`

Answer (score 0):

Enable the "Language" & "Interface Translation" modules.
Then download the translation .po file on https://localize.drupal.org and import it in /admin/config/regional/translate/import

Comment: Downloaded the  po file for project drupal core and imported it. But still I am seeing the month names in English.